# Is there a way like scrolling-x="no" and scrolling-y="yes" in iframe inside a jsf page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm in a jsf project and all of my xhtml pages are displaying inside an `<iframe>` ( see sample of code bellow) .So I need to hide the scroll in the HTML object inside this iframe. `#myIframe html: scroll-x:hidden;`.I tried many trials with no effects. This is my code.

```
<iframe id="content" name="content"  
   style="width: 100%; height: 100%" src="content.xhtml" scrolling="no">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

There is a solution with `scrolling="no"` but it prevent also the `overflow-y`. I just want to hide the `overflow-x` only.

So my question how could I reach the `<html>` DOM object inside this iframe
and how could I hide the `overflow-x` in this html element?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<iframe id="content" name="content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;" src="content.xhtml">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: it doesn't work because the  overflow-x: hidden; should affects on the html DOM attribute inside this iframe. :(

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the `iframe` in a `Div` and scroll the `div` instead of the `iframe`?